# Issue tracking system by function/method

Tags: issue-tracking

I often feel that it would be more convenient if, within an issue tracking system, each issue were attributed to a certain function/method. Then, we can easily list all the issues related to a certain function/method. Many issues can be clearly attributed to a certain function/method. At times, we may want to look at issues sorted by the posted/edited time or by importance, be many other times, we want to look through only the issues related to a certain function/method.

Of course, the system can be designed to be able to also display them mixed. And there are some issues that do not belong to a particular function/method, but they can be grouped together in some generic group.

1. Is there such issue tracking system out there?
2. Is there any problem with such system. If so, what are the problems?

Comment: More of a terminology preference, but I would consider replacing 'function/method' with 'symbol', to help encompass a more generic construct.  It may be that an issue can't be narrowly assigned to a particular function, but it might be appropriately assigned to a particular class or module or namespace, or even more distinctly to a vary particular variable or named constant or whatever else fits in your situation.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem is identifying the function or method in question.  Most bugs are entered by people not qualified to diagnose them to that level of detail.

Comment: I agree. To overcome that problem, what I had in mind is that, there is a default ("general") grouping for those issues that are not clear where they belong, and the moderator (or other  users) should later be able to assign a certain function/method to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish that we're using labels (also known as tags) in Jira. So we can also link one issue to multiple methods, search by methods and so on. We can already see which labels/tags are already used, how often they are used and send reports about specific peaks.

But that's not limited to Jira, you could use that way every issue tracker with a tag function.

Comment: That is a good idea.